# VR Project: Unresponsive UI After Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is a VR project.
After the build, the UI becomes unresponsive, despite everything appearing normal in the editor. Building individual scenes works correctly, but after the overall build, everything behaves differently.
Buttons show a highlight effect, but both buttons and dropdown menus are non-interactive.
What steps should I take? There are no suspicious entries in the log.

I have verified the components on the canvas, ensuring the presence of the canvas, canvas scaler, and Graphic Raycaster (Should I add a canvas group if it's not present?).
I have also confirmed the existence of the event system (although it is a Standalone Input Module).

Additionally, the RawImage used for displaying the minimap on the UI has become non-functional.

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.